# Ponteiros de ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, alocação, grafo

Bom galera, estou fazendo teoria dos grafos em C, e tentei usar alocação dinâmica para criar uma matriz. Além disso, meu código possui uma função para preencher a matriz com 1 nos índices recebidos. Porém estou com algum erro na alocação da matriz ou em seu preenchimento.

O código trava e retorna 3221225477

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct digraph //Estrutura do grafo, V e A são contadores, matrix_adj é um ponteiro para um array de ponteiros
{
    int V , A;
    int **matrix_adj;
};

typedef struct digraph* Digraph;
int **matrix_alloc(int r,int c,int val);
Digraph graph_alloc(int vertex);
void insert(Digraph G, int v, int w);
void show(Digraph G);

int main(void)
{
    Digraph G;
    G = graph_alloc(6);
    insert(G, 1,2);
    insert(G, 1,3);
    insert(G, 2,4);
    insert(G, 3,4);
    insert(G, 4,5);
    insert(G, 5,6);
    show(G);
    return 0;

}

int **matrix_alloc(int r,int c,int val)
{
    int i, j;
    int **matrix = (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));// aloca linhas
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(c*sizeof(int));//aloca colunas
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

Digraph graph_alloc(int vertex)
{
    Digraph G;
    G->V = vertex;
    G->A = 0;
    G->matrix_adj = matrix_alloc(vertex, vertex, 0);
    return G;
}

void insert(Digraph G,int v, int w)
{
    if(G->matrix_adj[v][w] == 0)
    {
        G->matrix_adj[v][w] = 1;
        G->matrix_adj[w][v] = 1;
        G->A++;
    }
}

void show(Digraph G)
{
    int v, w;
    for(v=0; v<G->V; v++)
    {
        for(w=0; w<G->V;w++)
        {
            printf("%d ", G->matrix_adj[v][w]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Vertices: ", G->V);
    printf("Arestas:  ", G->A);
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? Onde?

Comment: O programa abre e já para de funcionar, mas esse número grande de retorno que citei me faz acreditar que é algum erro de memória, na função insert ou matrix_alloc

Comment: Mostra a tabela ou o programa para antes disso? Experimentei o codigo e parece-me bem

Comment: No computador que estou atualmente, ele para de funcionar antes de mostrar, no q eu tenho em casa, mostra a matriz de saída, mas fica parado por uns segundos e depois a função main retorna 3221225477

Comment: Estranho, eu não estou tendo erros, o programa corre bem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atenção a este tipo de `typedefs`:

```
typedef struct digraph* Digraph;
```

Deve evitar este tipo de `typedefs` com ponteiros pois eles acabam a mascarar os tipos e dar lhe a ideia errada, consequentemente levando-o a cometer erros que normalmente não cometeria.

Repare que na função de criação do `graph_alloc`:

```
Digraph graph_alloc(int vertex)
{
    Digraph G;  // <---- aqui
    G->V = vertex;
    G->A = 0;
    G->matrix_adj = matrix_alloc(vertex, vertex, 0);
    return G;
}
```

Está a usar `Digraph G` como se fosse um `int` ou um tipo normal, mas na verdade é um ponteiro devido ao `typedef` que fez inicialmente. Seria igual ter feito:

```
struct digraph *G;
G->V = vertex;
```

Que está errado. O problema é que **está a criar um ponteiro, diz que no local apontado o `V` passa a valer `vertex`, mas não definiu para onde `G` aponta**. Por esse motivo o ponteiro estará a apontar para um local aleatório na memória.

Isto representa comportamento indefinido e potencial *segmentation fault*, que é o travar que indicou.

Tem várias soluções. A mais simples mantendo tudo o que está é fazer a alocação com `malloc`:

```
Digraph G = malloc(sizeof(struct digraph));
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/3dCrcx)

Pessoalmente aconselho a desfazer o `typedef` do ponteiro e utilizar um só para o tipo base a fim de evitar ter que escrever sempre `struct`, assim:

```
typedef struct digraph digraph;
```